# neural nets - How can I associate a confidence to my loss function?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network

I am trying doing OCC ([one class classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-class_classification)) using [an autoencoder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoencoder) based neural network.

To make a long story short I train my neural network with 200 matrices each containing 128 dataelements. Those are then compressed (see autoencoder).
Once the training is done I pass a new matrix to my neural net (test data) and based on the loss function I know whether the data I passed to it belongs to the target class or not.

I would like to know how I can compute a classification confidence in % based on the loss function I obtain when passing test data.

Thanks

In case it helps I am using Tensorflow

Answer (score -2):

Well actually normally you try to minimize your *cost* function (or in the case of one training observation your loss function). Normally the probability of the class you want to predict is not done using the loss function, but using a sigmoid output layer for example. You need a function that goes from 0 to 1 and that behaves like a probability. Where did you get the idea of using the loss function to evaluate your proabibility? But I am not an expert in one class classification (or outliers detection)... I guess you actually want the probability of your observation of **not** belonging to your class right?

Comment: No the endgoal is object recognition, so I want the probability of it to belong to the class.

Comment: From a first read this seems like an interesting article... https://togaware.com/papers/dawak02.pdf I don't think that simply using the loss function to identify classes is really easy or even have good mathematical grounds... Because from a really dumb point of view, if you train a network with **only** cats, the best thing it can do is to always predict cats, regardless of the inputs... Unless you have some test dataset to check it, it will probably always go in that direction. But possibly using different techniques you can overcome this problem...

Comment: Did you share the link to this paper because you think autoencoders are not suited?